# How to create ionic 2 infinite scroll with data from database

Tags: mysql, laravel, ionic2, httprequest, infinite-scroll

I'd query about 500 users from database who are active. I am using laravel and ionic framework.

Here is my query using laravel.

```
public function getUsers(Request $request) {
  $users = DB::table('users')->where('status', $request->status)->get();
  return Response::json($users);
}
```

Here might be my .ts code in ionic 2

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-users',
  templateUrl: 'users.html'
})
export class UsersPage {

  users: any = [];

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let data = { 'status': 'active'}
    this.http.post('http://path/to/laravel/api/getUsers', data, options)
    .subscribe(res => {
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(res['_body']);
      this.users = jsonData;
    })
  }
  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    // How can I do infinite scroll here??? 
    setTimeout(() => {
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 1000);
  }  
}
```

I am able to get the 500 active users and display it on my view.

However, It is a kind of laggy because there are too many data query at once.

I want to create infinite scroll to optimize the query. But, I don't know how to implement that in ionic 2.

I want atleast 10 users to be query everytime I scroll. Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just pull off one of my codes and replace some variable names. Hopefully it will make sense and be helpfull:

Assuming you have this on your html:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="fetchMore($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

You will need something like this on your .ts:

```
fetchMore(event) {
    this.myService.getMoreItems(10/*number of items to fetch*/,this.collection.length/*you might need to send the "skip" value*/).then(
      (moreItems: any[]) => {
        if (moreItems.length > 0) {
          this.collection = this.collection.concat(moreItems);
        }
        event.complete();
      },
      (err) => {
        event.complete();
      }
    );
  }
```

The `myService.getMoreItems` part will be your service/provider that has the function, return type is a `Promise<any>`, that will make the Http Request. I think you got the idea.